# Why contract addresses are larger than account addresses?

Tags: accounts, addresses

Why contract addresses are larger than account addresses?

For example:

- **'0xb794F5eA0ba39494cE839613fffBA74279579268'** - This is an account address
- **'0x756d5ef58a6617002255726a99b3b72f4c30ea25fc2be2de0c6bede5a71e4e54'** - This i s a contract address

Why is this?

Also, when I need to call `MyContract.at(myAddress)`with web3.js I need to shorten the contract address (instead it gives you an invalid address error). Any idea on how to do it?

Comment: A simple logic would be ease of identification, lets wait for any technical explanations.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, my fault.

The code I posted in the contract address is the tx hash where the contract was created.

I left the answer for anyone with the same confusion for the future

Comment: please add some more code details, that will better explain the issue